# TableLayoutPanel extremely slow

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am using `TableLayoutPanel` in C# (Forms).
My table is pretty big with its 33 columns and 8 rows. All cells contain `Label`-objects.

I have already set `DoubleBuffered = true;` of my TableLayoutPanel by creating a new subclass:

```
public class DoubleBufferedTableLayoutPanel : TableLayoutPanel
{
    public DoubleBufferedTableLayoutPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

If a user presses button X, all cell-controls are deleted and other labels are loaded into the table (from an array which contains all Label objects).

DEL: `this.table.Controls.Remove(this.table.GetControlFromPosition(col, row));`

ADD: `this.table.Controls.Add(this.labelArray[row, (col+pos)], col, row);`

Everything works fine, except that the progress of deleting the controls and adding the new ones takes five to ten seconds.

Is there a way other than to set `DoubleBuffered = true` in order to speed up this process?

Comment: Are you using Threading?

Comment: have you tried embedding your `Add`/`Remove` calls between `SuspendLayout` & `ResumeLayout` calls?

Comment: @LokiSinclair not while filling the table... How do I implement that best? Create two threads which both fill half the table?

Comment: @olydis Nope, but will try right now

Comment: @olydis +1 it's faster now but still a pretty long delay (a couple of seconds...)

Comment: @libjup what have you ended up with? I came across with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to avoid the slow processing of events in C#

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Visible = false;
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();

  // Processing Code

tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
tableLayoutPanel1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Could you explain what this actually does?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
TableLayoutPanel.GetType().GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .SetValue(TableLayoutPanel, true, null);
```

Comment: Hi Hamburger_Jack, welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for providing an answer. Rather than just a 'technical' copy and paste, the Stack Overflow community would benefit more if your answer gave more information as to what was wrong in the OP's example, and how your answer fixed it. People reading this want to see your insights, not just the final code. Jimbob

Comment: I think it’s just my coding style,
use GetProperty get "DoubleBuffered" Attributes ,Thereby modifying the DoubleBuffered inside the TableLayoutPanel ,I'm pretty sure this is useful

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but this sounds like a job for a datagridview, which is optimised for these tasks.

Comment: Do you wanna explain why you downvoted this or just randomly do it for no reason?

Comment: Your answer helped me in a similar problem.....Thanks I used to fill a tableLayoutPanel with data and it was extremly slow...after changing to datagridView It take up to 6 seconds to fill data which is so great
I recommend that you do not post an answer if you are not sure or you may post it as a comment... noone can downvote a comment

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the Data from the database to populate the tablelayoutpanel everytime you perform an action (postback)?

If so, consider lazy loading the data in to a bindable object once when the page first loads.
Then use the populated object when re binding (on Postback).

Comment: No; program starts, panel is initialized and array is created. This array is filled just once - not altered anytime later...